# Redesign with the use of template method and parametrized factory method. Dependency Inversion

Tags: .net, design-patterns

I decided to redesign a certain subsystem using recently aquired basic understanding of design patterns.

There are two abstractions that I can see and so they have become interfaces.  One follows *template method* (*IAnalyzer*) pattern because it has common algorithm for various scenarios (just basic operations differ) and puts data provided by second abstraction (parser) to a database.  The other abstraction,*IParser*, connects to some external datasource and retreives data from it.
I also added parametrized *Factory Method* class to the project which can create an instance of IParser and an instance of a IAnalyzer.  IAnalyzer contains a reference to IParser.  (Looks like *Strategy* to me, IAnalyzer serving as a Context and IParser as a Strategy but correct me if I'm wrong.)

For each possible realization of IParser there is some *settings* object which contains connection information.  Now, according to literature we may pass a parameter to factory pattern in order to instantiate an object.  So I'm thinking on using these settings objects as a parameter to a factory method that creates IParser.  In the next step I use another factory method to create IAnalyzer object using an instance of IParser created earlier as a parameter.

(Settings objects are stored in a serialized form on the disk and do not inherit from anything for right now.  May be they should?)  Basically I'm using if-else if logic in factory methods checking the type of a passed object to create parsers.  Whenever new type of parser needs to be created, so the corresponding settings object needs to be created as well.  Thus, adding new *else if* statement to factory method will take care of producing new parser.  (Actually there is one-to-many relationship btwn settings object and parser, b/c connection info may contain more than one addresses to connect to expecting identical datasources though.  So factory method will probably return an array of parsers.)

**Would generation of new classes based on settings object parameter violate *Dependency Inversion* principle** (*Abstractions should not depend on details, instead details should depend on abstractions*), do you think?

Here is some code.

```
  public class DSParsersFactory
{
    public static IParser[] CreateParsers(object ConnectionInfo)
    {
        if (ConnectionInfo == null) throw new ArgumentNullException();

        List<IParser> retVal = new List<IParser>();
        if (ConnectionInfo is MDSErverSettings)
        {
            //foreach address
            MDSServerSettingsAdapter sa = new MDSServerSettingsAdapter(); //realizes IAdapterConnectionInfo
            //init sa with current address
            IParser p = CreateParser(sa);
            if (p != null) retVal.Add(p);
        }
        else if (...)

        return retVal.ToArray();
    }

    static IParser CreateParser(IAdapterConnectionInfo ia)
    {
        if (ia is MDSServerSettingsAdapter)
            return new MDSParser(ia);
        else if(...)

        return null;
    }

    public static IAnalyzer CreateAnalyzer(IParser p)
    {
        if (p == null) throw new ArgumentNullException();

        if (p is MDSParser) return new MDSAnalyzer(p);
        else if (...)

        return null;
    }
}
```

What do you thnik?  Note that to extract multiple addresses from connection info object I created corresponding adapter classes that will hold single connection info to pass it to IParser constructor.  It's tedious but I haven't come up with anything better.  IAdapterConnectionInfo is really an empty interface right now.  I also don't like the idea of passing type System.Object to CreateParsers for some reason.

Thank you for your patience.

P.S. Main loop would look like this:

```
            var settings = Deserialize(path);

        IParser [] pArr = DSParsersFactory.CreateParsers(settings);

        foreach (IParser prs in pArr)
        {
            IAnalyzer algorithm = DSParsersFactory.CreateAnalyzer(prs);

            if (algorithm != null)
            {
                int nSuccesses = algorithm.ProcessData();

                string msg=string.Format("{0} records out of {1} were processed succussfully", nSuccesses, prs.GetDataCount());

                EventLog.WriteEntry(Settings.Default.AppName, msg);
            }
        }
```

Comment: Why you are returning an array from CreateParsers() but not the IEnumerable<>?

Comment: at least you can avoid ToArray() call and return retVal itself. I would say Array as return type it is smth like old style, but this is my personal point of view so do not care :)

Answer (score 1):

I find it really difficult to read your question, save the last paragraph and a few others, but I'll try to answer anyways.

From what I see in the code, instead of using `if` statements to determine the type of the `IAdapterConnectionInfo` object, you should just overload the method for each type. This would greatly increase efficiency and extensibility - I don't know if this is possible in your pattern, but if a new class inherited from an old one that implements `IAdapterConnectionInfo` and you checked for `ia is OldClass` before `ia is DerivedClass` you would lose specificity. Same goes for the `CreateParsers` method. The calling method can take care of the problems and use RTTI and casting on its side if need be, but your class doesn't rely on that design any more, which I think would be a good thing.

Another way to solve this would be to create a method in `IAdapterConnectionInfo` that returns the type of the correct related `ServerSettingsAdapter`, and another in the (may or may not exist) `IServerSettingsAdapter` that returns the appropriate `Parser` type. You can then use reflection and casting to load these. That may or may not work - I can't really tell.

Sorry if I didn't answer the right question... :P

Comment: Sorry for messy writing.  Diagrams aren't ready yet.  Do you mean overloading private static CreateParser(...) method?

Comment: @Nickolodeon: Yes, `CreateParser` and `CreateParsers`.

Comment: Actually, according to literature on design patterns casting object at client side is not good.  That's why they invent these patterns to make weak couplings.  I am thinking on modifying all those settings classes by making them implement interface to return collection of connections  (I guess it's a violation of an open-close principle, he-he ;).  And then I'll feed in settings class as an interface.  Thanks for your input, minitech, it made me think more.